# Horizontal line is not showing in table - tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray

[[image: Horizontal Line are not showing. ][1]]

How add those lines as below image, Any package to be added? bottom image from mdp journal; when I add same code to project report table content appears without horizontal lines.

```
\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{Classification report of 20s model  \label{tab-category-20}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCCC}
\toprule
\textbf{}   & \textbf{precision}    & \textbf{recall} & \textbf{f1-score}\\
\midrule
Category 1      & 1.00          & 1.00           & 1.00\\
Category 2      & 0.99          & 0.99           & 0.99\\
Category 3      & 0.98          & 1.00           & 0.99\\
Category 4      & 0.99          & 0.98           & 0.98\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\unskip
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the compilable TeX code resulting in your table. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: With your code sniped I cant reproduce your problem. All declared rules in table are present.

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). As @Mensch said, you need to show *compilable* code. There may be some special macro in your preamble that interferes with table formating.

Comment: toprule bottomrule are not defined by default, do you get an undefined command error?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting your code snippet into working `article` document where are in preamble loaded all needed paclages works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{Classification report of 20s model}
\label{tab-category-20}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCCC} 
    \toprule 
\textbf{} & \textbf{precision} & \textbf{recall} & \textbf{f1-score}\\ 
    \midrule 
Category 1  & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  \\
Category 2  & 0.99  & 0.99  & 0.99  \\
Category 3  & 0.98  & 1.00  & 0.99  \\
Category 4  & 0.99  & 0.98  & 0.98  \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You may like the same table written by help of `tabularray` package (version 2022B) with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which load packages of the same names):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
      \begin{table}[ht]
      \centering
\caption{Classification report of 20s model}
\label{tab-category-20}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l SSS},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c, guard}
             }
    \toprule
            & precision 
                    & recall    
                            & f1-score  \\
    \midrule
Category 1  & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00      \\
Category 2  & 0.99  & 0.99  & 0.99      \\
Category 3  & 0.98  & 1.00  & 0.99      \\
Category 4  & 0.99  & 0.98  & 0.98      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]